# Unable to submit data to database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a blog app with django.When I visit localhost the home page works and when I click on register tab the register page comes and when I click on submit it's not submitting the data to the database. It returns page not found error. request method:POST .Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/register/register.I think the problem is with 
url.

**html code**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="box">
    <h2>
        <center>Register</center>
    </h2><br>
    <form action='register' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label><b>Email:</b></label><br>
        <input type="email" class="inputvalues" name="email"/><br>
        <label><b>Username:</b></label><br>
        <input type="text" maxlength="100" class="inputvalues" 
                                           name="User_name"/><br>
        <label><b>Password:</b></label><br>
        <input type="password" class="inputvalues" name="Paasword1"/><br>
        <label><b>Confirm Password:</b></label><br>
        <input type="password" class="inputvalues" name="Paasword2"/><br>
        <input type="Submit" id="lg"/><br>
        <center><a href="#" >Already have an account.Login here.</a> 
                                                              </center>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**my main app urls.py code**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
 path('blog/',include('blog.urls')),
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**blog app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.homepage),
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',views.login),     
]
```

**views.py register page code**

```
def register(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    email=request.POST['email']
    User_name=request.POST['User_name']
    Password1=request.POST['Password1']
    Password2=request.POST['Password2']
    if Password1 == Password2:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            print('13')
        elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            print("email taken")
        else:
            user = 
               User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                                          password=Password1,email=email)
            user.save();
  else:
    return render(request,'register.html')
<!----------layout.html-->
 {% load static %}
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Self Learn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/main.css' 
                                                                       %}" />
 </head>
 <body>    
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo">Blog</h1> 
        <ul class="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="login/">Login</a>
            <a href='register/'>Register</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="{% static 'images\12.PNG' %}" class="logo1"/>
    </a>
    <!----Post------>
    {% for blog in blog %}
    <div class="list">
        <div class="con">
            <h3 style="color:DodgerBlue;">{{blog.author}}</h3>
            <h6 style="font-family: montserrat,sans-serif;"> On 22</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="con">
            <h1><b>{{blog.title}}</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="con">
            <p>{{blog.desc}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I click on the register tab once it returns register.html file at that 
time the URL is http://12e not found error and at that time URL is 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/register/register

Comment: Assuming the html code is for register.html, did you try setting the form action to '/'?

Comment: Yes Didn't worked.

Comment: Try `'/register'`.

Comment: I tried didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You're using the URL on your HTML in a wrong way. You should do like this:

```html
<form action="{% 'register' %}" method='POST'>
....
</form>
```

Comment: I tried adding '{% "register" %}' in action.But it returns "TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/register/
Invalid block tag on line 7: ''register'', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean but you should be able to access `http://localhost:8000/blog/register`

Comment: Can you post your error stack so we can what's happening? Also if you can post your `layout.html` would be good too

Comment: I enclosed my layout.html in above question code section.What is 'post your error stack '?I didn't understand?

Comment: I meant your stacktrace, the error displayed in the terminal

Comment: C:\Users\PC\main>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 17, 2019 - 16:34:22
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'main.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[17/Jun/2019 16:34:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1964
[17/Jun/2019 16:34:29] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1584
Not Found: /register/register
[17/Jun/2019 16:34:35] "POST /register/register HTTP/1.1" 404 2462  #Stacktrace

Comment: I've edited my answer, basically swapping the single quotes to double quotes, although I don't think that's the issue, but can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

```
  form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
```

Use always " " in html file, not ' '

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.The problem is not installing python extension with my ide.After installing that it worked.